PDF printing very slow on HP Laserjet with CUPS
I have a headless CUPS server running on ubuntu server 22.04 with an HP Laserjet 5200L attached via USB.
I have installed hplip from APT and printing works. Except it is dog slow for PDF files, which after reading around might be caused by a PDF rendering bottleneck. Note that previously PDF printing did not work at all with the following error from CUPS web interface:

"Use "pdftops-renderer" option (see cups-filters README
file) to use Ghostscript or MuPDF for the PDF -> PostScript
conversion."

Troubleshooting this, I ended up running this command: lpadmin -p HP_LaserJet_5200L -o pdftops-renderer-default=pdftops
Trying to find which driver I am using, I ran grep Version /etc/cups/ppd/HP_LaserJet_5200L.ppd and got:
*%               PPD File Version Information
*FileVersion: "1.1"
*FormatVersion: "4.3"
*LanguageVersion: English
*%               Product Version Information
*PSVersion: "(3010.107) 0"

Does this indicate that the PPD driver I am using does not support postscript? Or did I mess up the render setting? Is that even an HPLIP driver that is active on my system?

FWIW I have a similar setup, with Cups running on Ubuntu Server on a Raspberry Pi. PDF printing is very slow when printing from a MacOS client, but fast from a Ubuntu, Windows or Android client. Never got to the bottom of that.
